# Sorting a nesting list by the first item -- itemgetter not doing the trick

Tags: python, list, sorting, nested

I have a dictionary that I've converted to a list so I can sort by the first item.  The key in the dictionary is a string (of numbers), the value is an integer which is maintained in the list.
The list from the dictionary conversion looks like:

```
[('228055', 1), ('228054', 1), ('228057', 2), ('228056', 1), ('228051', 1), ('228050', 1),     ('228053', 1), ('203184', 6), ('228059', 1), ('228058', 1), ('89370', 2), ('89371', 3), ('89372', 2), ('89373', 1), ('89374', 1), ('89375', 1), ('89376', 1), ('89377', 1), ('89378', 1), ('89379', 1),.........]
```

There are around 240,000 items in the dictionary.  I would like to sort the dictionary by the first index, but when I use itemgetter(0) it sorts the list by all the "1's" first.  The sorted listed looks like:

```
[('0', 3), ('1', 3), ('10', 3), ('100', 4), ('1000', 3), ('10000', 1), ('100000', 3), ('100001', 2), ('100002', 3), ('100003', 3), ('100004', 2), ('100005', 2), ('100006', 2), ('100007', 2), ('100008', 2), ('100009', 2), ('10001', 1), ('100010', 3), ('100011', 3), ('100012', 3), ('100013', 2), ('100014', 1), ('100015', 1), ('100016', 1), ('100017', 1), ('100018', 1), ....]
```

I would like the list to be sorted by ['0', 3), ('1', 3), ('2', integer), ('3', integer),...('240,000', integer)]

Here's my code where I'm reading in a text file to a dictionary, converting to a list and used itemgetter to sort by first item in nested list.  I need the dictionary in the code because I heavily depend on it to look up values by the key.  I'm only trying to sort the dictionary for the output file once all the processes are ran.  Thanks for any help.

```
import sys, string, csv, arcpy, os, fileinput, traceback
from arcpy import env
from operator import itemgetter


#Creating a dictionary of FID: LU_Codes from external txt file
text_file = open("H:\SWAT\NC\FID_Whole_Copy.txt", "rb")
#Lines = text_file.readlines()
FID_GC_dict =  dict()
reader = csv.reader(text_file, delimiter='\t')
for line in reader:
    FID_GC_dict[line[0]] = int(line[1])
text_file.close()

dict_List = [(x, FID_GC_dict[x]) for x in FID_GC_dict.keys()]
dict_List.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
print dict_List
```

Comment: `text_file = open(r"H:\SWAT\NC\FID_Whole_Copy.txt")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Changing the key to convert the string to an int will help you, also here are some other sorting tips.

```
from operator import itemgetter

list_to_sort=[('89372', 2), ('89373', 1), ('89374', 1), ('89375', 1), ('89376', 1),     ('89377', 1), ('228055', 1), ('228054', 1), ('228057', 2), ('228056', 1), ('228051', 1), ('228050', 1),('228053', 1), ('203184', 6), ('228059', 1), ('228058', 1), ('89370', 2), ('89371', 3), ('89372', 2), ('89373', 1), ('89374', 1), ('89375', 1), ('89376', 1), ('89377', 1)]
print list_to_sort

list_to_sort.sort()
print list_to_sort # badly sorted as described

list_to_sort.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
print list_to_sort # badly sorted as described (same as above)

list_to_sort.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
print list_to_sort # sorted well

list_to_sort.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]), reverse=True)
print list_to_sort # sorted well in reverse
```

Side note on building the list to sort from the dict. `iteritems()` is a nicer way of doing what you do with the following

```
dict_List = [(x, FID_GC_dict[x]) for x in FID_GC_dict.keys()]

dict_List = [(k,v) for k,v in FID_GC_dict.iteritems()]
```

Comment: Please test your code before posting it; these "tips" are broken.  Your first "gen_sorted=" line won't work: a genexp doesn't have a .sort() method.  For your "[k, v in FID_GC_dict.iteritems()]" the syntax is wrong -- there's no "for", so this is "[k, (v in FID_GC_dict.iteritems())] Neither of your final two "one lined tuned" answers will work, because you've combined your mistakes.  I've never downvoted an answer, ever, but I am very tempted this time.  Linda: please do not learn Python from this "answer".  @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams was concise, but correct, and unlike this, not misleading.

Comment: Yes I rushed this, it wasn't tested and I thought sort on a list returned a iterable. It doesn't my notes above and answer has been totally changed. Thanks for the feedback DSM some points I will remember.

Comment: DSM's comments no longer hold, the answer has been updated and fixed, tested and verified based on his feedback

Comment: Assuming that you're using Python 2 -- which you must be, because iteritems() doesn't exist in Python 3 -- then your last two "nicer ways" are simply verbose ways to write FID_GC_dict.items().

Answer (score 15):

That's because they're strings.

```
key=lambda x: int(x[0])
```

Comment: Why can't one do key=int(itemgetter(0))? I get this error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'operator.itemgetter'. Oh well, I'll use lambda.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: `operator.itemgetter()` returns a function. You can't convert a function to an integer.