# Python reordering the list of lists after sorting

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

I'm fetching data from two separate tables as shown below.

```
list_table_1 = models.my_table_1.objects.all().order_by("-date_field","time_field") ## data from table 1
list_table_2 = models.my_table_2.objects.all().order_by("-date_field","time_field") ## data from table 2
```

Then I put both the lists in single list say `my_list` and would like to sort them based on the date and also the time in reverse order such that the most recent order is on top. So I did this :
`my_list(key= lambda item:item[0][1],reverse= True)`

then I get this :

```
[['InstaMojo', datetime.date(2015, 6, 30), datetime.time(10, 50, 54), u'status',u'buyer_name'], ['InstaMojo',datetime.date(2015, 6, 29), datetime.time(19, 46, 22), u'status', u'buyer_name'],['PayU',datetime.date(2015, 6, 30), datetime.time(15, 39, 11), u'status', u'firstname'], ['PayU', datetime.date(2015, 6, 29), datetime.time(15, 37, 29), u'status', u'firstname']]
```

But I need output like the following:

```
[['PayU',datetime.date(2015, 6, 30), datetime.time(15, 39, 11), u'status', u'firstname'],['InstaMojo', datetime.date(2015, 6, 30), datetime.time(10, 50, 54), u'status',u'buyer_name'] ,['InstaMojo',datetime.date(2015, 6, 29), datetime.time(19, 46, 22), u'status', u'buyer_name'], ['PayU', datetime.date(2015, 6, 29), datetime.time(15, 37, 29), u'status', u'firstname']]
```

Any help in this regard would be great! Thanks in advance!

BTW I have looked into these questions on SO - [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446953/sorting-a-nesting-list-by-the-first-item-itemgetter-not-doing-the-trick)
and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117392/sorting-elements-from-a-nested-based-on-the-second-element-in-each-nested-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a tuple `(date, time)` for each key

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda x:(x[1], x[2]), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Your `key` seems  to be wrong.

```
lambda item:item[0][1]
```

will always give you the first charachter of  element at `[0]` th index. If ypu wish to sort on basis of date use this as key.

```
key= lambda x :x[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This produces the output you want:

```
my_list = sorted(my_list, key=operator.itemgetter(1, 2), reverse=True)
```

What you have in your code is sorting by the second item of the first item:  `item[0]` is the first item, and `item[0][1]` is the second item of that.  So you were sorting by the 'n' in 'Instamojo', the 'a' in 'PayU', etc.

`operator.itemgetter` has the semantics you're looking for; it selects a tuple from the input, in this case, (second-item, third-item).  Then `sorted` (or `list.sort`) sorts them lexicographically, so that if the dates are the same, they are compared by time.

Comment: Thanks for swift reply! I wanted something of this kind