# Python: sort list except first line

Tags: python, list, sorting, line

I have this list :

```
[['Nom', 'Francais', 'Anglais', 'Maths'], ['Catherine', '9', '17', '9'], ['Karim', '12', '15', '11'], ['Rachel', '15', '15', '14'], ['Roger', '12', '14', '12'], ['Gabriel', '7', '13', '8'], ['Francois', '14', '8', '15'], ['Henri', '10', '12', '13'], ['Stephane', '18', '12', '8'], ['Karine', '9', '10', '10'], ['Marie', '10', '10', '10'], ['Claire', '15', '9', '12'], ['Marine', '12', '9', '12']]
```

I want to sort it with the names (or, in another words, by alphabetical order of the [0] element of each list within the list) but i don't want don't want the first list (`['Nom', 'Francais', 'Anglais', 'Maths']`) to be sorted with the others , how can in do that ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Did you try something? and what do you mean by the first line? the first element in the list?

Comment: I mean i want that ['Nom', 'Francais', 'Anglais', 'Maths'] stay first, and then the others elements are sorted. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Better question: why are you storing header information in the list itself?

Comment: Okay, to skip the first element you can use list slicing, something like `my_list[1:]`

Comment: The goal is to create a csv file after sorting the names, so i need this header information in the list !

Comment: Ok thank you ettanany i'm going to check that and try !

Comment: Maxime - is there a reason you can't use a dictionary or dataframe for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting a nesting list by the first item -- itemgetter not doing the trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446953/sorting-a-nesting-list-by-the-first-item-itemgetter-not-doing-the-trick). For sorting the list, skipping first index. You have to *slice* the list like: `my_list[1:]`

Answer (score 5):

You can use range assignment:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint # just to have a nice display
>>> data = [['Nom', 'Francais', 'Anglais', 'Maths'], ['Catherine', '9', '17', '9'], ['Karim', '12', '15', '11'], ['Rachel', '15', '15', '14'], ['Roger', '12', '14', '12'], ['Gabriel', '7', '13', '8'], ['Francois', '14', '8', '15'], ['Henri', '10', '12', '13'], ['Stephane', '18', '12', '8'], ['Karine', '9', '10', '10'], ['Marie', '10', '10', '10'], ['Claire', '15', '9', '12'], ['Marine', '12', '9', '12']]
>>> pprint(data)
[['Nom', 'Francais', 'Anglais', 'Maths'],
 ['Catherine', '9', '17', '9'],
 ['Karim', '12', '15', '11'],
 ['Rachel', '15', '15', '14'],
 ['Roger', '12', '14', '12'],
 ['Gabriel', '7', '13', '8'],
 ['Francois', '14', '8', '15'],
 ['Henri', '10', '12', '13'],
 ['Stephane', '18', '12', '8'],
 ['Karine', '9', '10', '10'],
 ['Marie', '10', '10', '10'],
 ['Claire', '15', '9', '12'],
 ['Marine', '12', '9', '12']]
>>> data[1:] = sorted(data[1:])
>>> pprint(data)
[['Nom', 'Francais', 'Anglais', 'Maths'],
 ['Catherine', '9', '17', '9'],
 ['Claire', '15', '9', '12'],
 ['Francois', '14', '8', '15'],
 ['Gabriel', '7', '13', '8'],
 ['Henri', '10', '12', '13'],
 ['Karim', '12', '15', '11'],
 ['Karine', '9', '10', '10'],
 ['Marie', '10', '10', '10'],
 ['Marine', '12', '9', '12'],
 ['Rachel', '15', '15', '14'],
 ['Roger', '12', '14', '12'],
 ['Stephane', '18', '12', '8']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd do something like this.  But it assumes you're semi-comfortable with Pandas.  This gives you a lot more flexibility to do more with the data.

```
import pandas as pd

nl = [['Nom', 'Francais', 'Anglais', 'Maths'], ['Catherine', '9', '17', '9'], ['Karim', '12', '15', '11'], ['Rachel', '15', '15', '14'], ['Roger', '12', '14', '12'], ['Gabriel', '7', '13', '8'], ['Francois', '14', '8', '15'], ['Henri', '10', '12', '13'], ['Stephane', '18', '12', '8'], ['Karine', '9', '10', '10'], ['Marie', '10', '10', '10'], ['Claire', '15', '9', '12'], ['Marine', '12', '9', '12']]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = nl[0])

for l, c in zip(nl[0], range(4)):
    df[l] = [ r[c] for r in nl[1:] ]

df.sort_values(by = 'Nom', inplace = True)
df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
```

which yields:

```
          Nom Francais Anglais Maths
0   Catherine        9      17     9
1      Claire       15       9    12
2    Francois       14       8    15
3     Gabriel        7      13     8
4       Henri       10      12    13
5       Karim       12      15    11
6      Karine        9      10    10
7       Marie       10      10    10
8      Marine       12       9    12
9      Rachel       15      15    14
10      Roger       12      14    12
11   Stephane       18      12     8
```

and then if you need a .csv per your most recent comment, it's simply:

```
df.to_csv('/directory/my_filename.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: Ok down-vote trolls... what's wrong with this one?  Please speak your mind if you think this is a bad solution.  I'm pretty sure it does exactly what the OP wants it to do.  Down votes without explanation discourage people from posting relevant answers and drag down the entire site.